# SQLAlchemyCRUDRouter custom GET routes with params

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have the following code:

```py
from fastapi import Depends, HTTPException
from fastapi_crudrouter import SQLAlchemyCRUDRouter
from dependencies import get_db
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from pydantic import BaseModel
from db import Turns
import dependencies as deps

class TurnsCreate(BaseModel):
        id_space : int
        name : str
        sgl : str

class TurnSchema(TurnsCreate):
        id_turn : int 

        class Config:
            orm_mode = True

router = SQLAlchemyCRUDRouter( schema=TurnSchema, create_schema=TurnsCreate, db_model=Turns, db=get_db, delete_all_route=False )

@router.get('/{id_space}')
def get_tr( id_space : int, db : Session = Depends(deps.get_db) ):
    try:
        print("test")
        return db.query( 
        Turnos.id_space,
        Turnos.name,
        Turnos.sgl,
        )\
        .filter( id_space = id_space )\
        .all()
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=repr(e))
    
@router.get('/')
def get_tr( db : Session = Depends(deps.get_db) ):
    try:
        return db.query( 
        Turnos.id_space,
        Turnos.name,
        Turnos.sgl,
        )\
        .all()
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=repr(e))
```

**Model**

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, ForeignKey, String, Boolean, Float
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import INTEGER

class Turns(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'turns'
    id_turn = Column(INTEGER(11), primary_key = True)
    id_space = Column(INTEGER(11), ForeignKey(Espacios.idEspacio))
    name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    sgl = Column(String(15), nullable=True)
```

I'm trying to have 2 GET routes: One should return all objects, and the other one should return only the objects with a specific `id_space`. So at the end, PUT, POST and DELETE methods should behave normal, and GET should do what I want it to do.

The `print("test")` does not work. Is there a way to do this with `SQLAlchemyCRUDRouter` or do I have to use `APIRouter` to do this?

Comment: Where are you creating your FastAPI app and registering your router? Also, the point of SQLAlchemy crud router is that you shouldn't have to actually write the controllers yourself, they will be pre-created as part of the SQLAlchemyCRUDRouter.

Comment: @MatsLindh I created FastAPI and router in a separate file. I want to keep the DELETE, PUT and POST routes as SQLAlchemyCRUDRouter default. I was just wondering if I could override the behaviour of the GET route. That's why I was using SQLAlchemyCRUDRouter.

Comment: Did you try overriding the existing path? `@router.get('/{item_id}')` (i.e. the same pattern has what CRUDRouter uses interally? It's the pattern used as an example in https://fastapi-crudrouter.awtkns.com/routing#overriding-routes

Comment: @MatsLindh I tried to override `@router.get('/{item_id}')` and `@router.get('/')` but it didn't do what I wrote inside those routes.